# Include scala source files in sbt pack output jar

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

How can the scala source files of a project be included in the generated target jar produced by [sbt pack](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack)?

Currently, when an IDE user of my jar tries to jump to a function in the library they will only get decompiled version of the code instead of the original source. However, other libraries pull from artifact repositories have the ability to jump to the original source code.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: That should be handled by SBT publishing a sources JAR. That's not the goal of SBT pack

Comment: sbt-pack doesn't create jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

> packageSrc: Creates a jar file containing all main source files and
> resources. The packaged paths are relative to src/main/scala and
> src/main/resources. Similarly, test:packageSrc operates on test source
> files and resources.

[sbt Command Line Reference](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html)

Comment: so it is a very basic function of the sbt, but that does something else than sbt-pack or sbt-assembly. so it doesn't answer the question as it is written. it is a shame

Comment: The question owner had a problem and the answer solved his problem.